# How do i update an application after pusblishing it in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, auto-update

I published an application,when publishing it i checked that the application should check for updates-now how do i make it realy check for updates-where should i put the new files and in which format?

Comment: You are going to need to give just a bit more detail to what you did.   What type of application.  (Publish i assume means Web Applications)  How did you publish the application.  What type of updates are you talking about?

Comment: @Sergei I have an winfroms application-it is going to be disturbed by cd(email or something like this) and i want an autoupdate mechanisem- i saw that you can use the built in auto updater-i want that everytime the application is started it will check for updates-where should i placed the new published app?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need it on some kind of Web server.

I would imigine that you also want some authentication so that only the application it self can gain access to the new version of the software.

Comment: well how do i configure that? what should i do? thats not realy an answer :P

Comment: I disagree, surely you'd want people to be able to download the new version too? I see nothing that needs to be protected there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean you are using CLickOnce as the installer.  If you want the app to check for updates every time it is ran you need to publish to a location all the apps can see.  If this is an internal app I believe a network share will do.  If not then you need to publish to a web server or ftp server.

Comment: just publishing it to an ftp will do?

Comment: i can publish that app to an ftp server but then it askes for updates location- IIS server,local or website-what should i do?

Comment: The location all depends on where the app will live and what it can have access too.  If it will not go across NAT or firewalls then a UNC path should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClickOnce as nportelli mentioned above, or you can use a 3rd party utility to do the heavy lifting for you.

I wrote an open-source library to do just that transparently - including an external update application to do the actual cold update. See http://www.code972.com/blog/2010/08/nappupdate-application-auto-update-framework-for-dotnet/

The code is at http://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate (Licensed under the Apache 2.0 license)